# MySQL Query: GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, subquery

I need help building a query.

I have two tables. One his called jobs_certs and the other is called users_certs.

The jobs_certs table contains the certificates required to apply for a job. Each required certificate has it's own row, with the job_id representing the job posting the required certificate is attached to, and cert_id representing the id attached to that certificate.

The users_certs table contains all the certificates a user possesses. Each certificate has it's own row, with the uid representing the user's id and the cert_id representing the id of the certificate the user possesses.

I need to see if a user possesses all the certificates required for the job. So I tried something like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cert_id) as certs, uid 
FROM users_certs 
HAVING certs = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cert_id) FROM jobs_certs WHERE job_id = 6)
```

But I'm not getting any results back. How should I go about something like that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rather than describing the table structure in English, use [sample code](http://sscce.org/) in the form of `CREATE` statements. It's much clearer. Also, sample data (as `INSERT` statements) and desired results is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go. Create an inline view for the job certs and another one for the user certs and then `inner join` them together on the list of `cert_id` (make sure that there is an `order by` in that `GROUP_CONCAT` to make the result of the `GROUP_CONCAT` deterministic):

```
select users.uid
from
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cert_id order by cert_id asc) as certs, uid 
FROM users_certs 
group by uid) users
inner join
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cert_id order by cert_id asc) as certs, job_id 
FROM jobs_certs
where job_id = 6
group by job_id) jobs
on jobs.certs = users.certs;
```

Or you could even dress the query up a bit to return all users whether they have the required certs or not with a `hasRequiredCerts` column:

```
select users.uid,case when job_id is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end as hasRequiredCerts
from
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cert_id order by cert_id asc) as certs, uid 
FROM users_certs 
group by uid) users
left join
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cert_id order by cert_id asc) as certs, job_id 
FROM jobs_certs
where job_id = 6 
group by job_id) jobs
on jobs.certs = users.certs;
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the tenets of the relational model is that column values should be simple rather than compound; in the vernacular, it's known as [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) (1NF). While there are valid uses for `GROUP_CONCAT` (which produces a relation that's not 1NF), it's tripping you up here. Instead, focus on the desired results: select the certifications that a user is missing for a job. You can do this with a left or right join on the certification ID, selecting those rows where the user is NULL.

```
SELECT jc.cert_id
    FROM jobs_certs AS jc
    LEFT JOIN users_certs AS uc ON jc.cert_id = uc.cert_id
    WHERE jc.job_id = ? AND uc.cert_id IS NULL
```

If there are no missing certifications, the user is fully qualified. Alternatively, you can select `COUNT(jc.cert_id)` to get the number of missing certifications.